# How to allow only https requests in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

can we restrict our REST API in spring boot to allow the only https request, without any certificates

Comment: Suggest reading [how https works](https://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/) and you will see that a certificate is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this link for basic https restriction on Spring boot app: https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/.

Concerning certificate outside of the application classpath, look at the `server.ssl.key-store` property:

```
server.port: 8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store:/etc/your/path/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: <your-password>
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Comment: Thanks for info...... sorry maybe my question was not quite clear, can we do this without involving any certificates

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's not possible, you need either generate a self-signed certifcate or get one from a Certificate Authority.